# Dynamic query runs successfully but does nothing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `#months` as below

```
MONTH_ID    FISCAL_YEAR_MONTH   MIN_DATE    MAX_DATE
1               FSA201510       20151001    20151031
2               FSA201511       20151101    20151130
3               FSA201512       20151201    20151204
```

I am using below dynamic query to update a column `SCCount` in table `mastercount`(has 3 rows)-

```
   DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000),


   set @sql=
   'DECLARE @I INT,                    
             @ROWS INT,
             @fym varchar(6) 

   SET @ROWS=(SELECT count(*) from #MONTHS)      
   SET @I=1        
   WHILE @I<=@ROWS          
   BEGIN
    SET @fym=(SELECT RIGHT(FISCAL_YEAR_MONTH,6) from #MONTHS where month_id=@I)
    UPDATE mastercount 
    SET SCCount = (SELECT count(*) 
    FROM dw_extract.dbo.dw_fsa_'+cast(@fym as varchar(6))+'    
    )
    WHERE row=@I
    set @I=@I+1
    end'
   exec (@sql)
```

Above query gives error: `Must declare the scalar variable "@fym".`

Comment: What is @fym? It isn't declare in your dynamic sql. The data structures you have here are going to be a constant battle. I would argue that your dynamic does not run successfully, otherwise you wouldn't have a reason to post a question. :) You have a lot of scope problems here. Your variables defined outside dynamic sql are not in scope in your dynamic sql.

Comment: @SeanLange Hey! I am new to dynamic query. Sorry for confusion. I have changed the query with error.

Comment: That is because the variable @fym is NOT available outside your dynamic sql. I really don't see any reason you need a loop here. I have to run for the day but if nobody comes along to help I can give you a hand tomorrow. This can be made a LOT simpler than what you have going on here so far.

Comment: Sure. Please come back when you have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make the `UPDATE` dynamic:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000), @fym varchar(6)

DECLARE @I INT, @ROWS INT

SET @ROWS=(SELECT count(*) from #MONTHS)      
SET @I=1    

WHILE @I<=@ROWS          
BEGIN
    SET @fym=(SELECT RIGHT(FISCAL_YEAR_MONTH,6) from #MONTHS where month_id=@I)

    SET @sql = 'UPDATE mastercount'
    SET @sql += ' SET SCCount = (SELECT count(*) '
    SET @sql += ' dw_extract.dbo.dw_fsa_' + cast(@fym as varchar(6))+ ') WHERE row=' + @I

    EXEC (@sql)

    SET @I=@I+1
END
```

Comment: Tried. Throwing error -  `Must declare the scalar variable "@I"`

Comment: @Karver01, Updated the answer to not to get the error.

Comment: You really don't need a loop for this. A tally table would a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this using a tally table instead of a loop. If your loop really is only ever going to be three this isn't going to make a lot of difference. But if the number of iterations increases this will have a huge impact on performance.

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max) = '';

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E2
    )

select @sql = @sql + 'UPDATE mastercount set SCCount = (select count(*) from dw_extract.dbo.dw_fsa_' 
    + (SELECT RIGHT(FISCAL_YEAR_MONTH,6) from #MONTHS where month_id = t.N)
    + ') WHERE row = ' + CAST(t.N as varchar(6)) + ';'
from cteTally t
where t.N < (SELECT count(*) from #MONTHS)

exec sp_executesql @sql
```